# Access Data annotations in a component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I want to create a generic input component like that:

```cs
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<div class="mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-floating flex-grow-1">
            <InputText id="@ValueId" @bind-Value="Value" class="form-control" placeholder=" "/>
            <label for="@ValueId">@(LabelText + (IsRequired ? " *" : string.Empty))</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string ValueId { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string LabelText { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The component creates an Input field with the corresponding label text and adds an Asterisk (`*`) if the field is required. My issue is that I have to pass four parameters to the input field like that:

```html
<GenericInput  ValueId="@nameof(MyDto.MyProperty)"
               LabelText="My Property"
               IsRequired="@_myDto.IsRequired(nameof(MyDto.MyProperty))"
               Value="@_myDto.MyProperty">
</GenericInput>
```

I want to use only the property as a parameter and do all the other stuff in my component. The best would be if I could switch in the component depending on the property type to use `InputText` or `InputNumber` if I have an int property. Still, the real question is: How to get the "whole" property as a parameter in my component and not just its value?

I think it doesn't matter but for the sake of completeness, the `IsRequired` extensions method looks like this:

```cs
public static bool IsRequired(this object obj, string propertyName)
{
    var objectType = obj.GetType();
    var property = objectType.GetProperty(propertyName);
    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found on type '{objectType.Name}'");
    }
    return property.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().Any();
}
```

Comment: Side Note: Why are you using the [Required] attributes in your component like that? Does that actually work? Should it not be [EditorRequired]?

Comment: You are right, I thought I would get a VS warning if I don't set the required fields in the parent component but that does not happen. I removed the required annotations in my question.

Comment: Generic Inputs are normally part of a generic form.  Here's a property in a data object, figure out how to display the correct edit input.  Seems simple enough , everyone starts on a text box.  Then numbers, then "How do I solve the select".,  Where do the option values come from, .....   And then you come to submission and validation,....    You sort of build a horrendously fiendish complex system to solve all these problems, and then someone says, "but why can't we put these two fields on the same row when the page is wide enough".  There are questions on here every week seeking to do this.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis, that's why I build a generic input and not a generic form.

Comment: [Polite] The generic component is the hard bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Here is a basic simplified component:

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using System.Reflection
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

@typeparam T


<h3>GenericInput</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<T>>? Property { get; set; }
    
    
    
    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        //This is the type of the property e.g. string, int,...
        var valueType = typeof(T);
        var propertyLambda = Property;
        if (propertyLambda == default)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Expression body is null");
        }
        if (propertyLambda.Body is not MemberExpression member)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a method, not a property.",
                propertyLambda.ToString()));
        }
        
        if (member.Member is not PropertyInfo propInfo)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                "Expression '{0}' refers to a field, not a property.",
                propertyLambda.ToString()));
        }
        
        //This checks if the Required annotation is set on the property
        var isRequired = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().Any();
        //This is the actual value of the property
        var result = propertyLambda.Compile().Invoke();
    }
}
```

And it is called like that:

```html
<GenericInput Property="@(() => _artilysin.PatentInformation)"></GenericInput>
```

Comment: Do you need to run this in `OnParametersSet`?  This is expensive code which in this incarnation is run every time the component [and the parent component tree] is rendered.  Check if the expression reference has changed?  You can put in some debug console print code to see how often it's run.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this by using an Expression parameter to capture the property access expression, and then evaluate the details such as value, name, etc., from within the component.

Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
@typeparam TValue
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<div class="mb-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-floating flex-grow-1">
            @if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int))
            {
                <InputNumber id="@ValueId" @bind-Value="Value" class="form-control" placeholder=" " />
            }
            else
            {
                <InputText id="@ValueId" @bind-Value="Value" class="form-control" placeholder=" " />
            }
            <label for="@ValueId">@(LabelText + (IsRequired ? " *" : string.Empty))</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<TValue>> For { get; set; }

    public string ValueId => For.GetMemberExpression()?.Member?.Name ?? string.Empty;

    public string LabelText => ValueId.ReplaceCamelCaseWithSpaces(); // You can create a method to convert CamelCase to space-separated string

    public bool IsRequired => For.GetMemberExpression()?.Member?.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<RequiredAttribute>().Any() ?? false;

    public TValue Value
    {
        get => For.Compile().Invoke();
        set
        {
            var memberExpression = For.GetMemberExpression();
            if (memberExpression != null)
            {
                var obj = ((ConstantExpression)memberExpression.Expression).Value;
                var property = (PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member;
                property.SetValue(obj, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use this custom input component in your page like so:

```
<DemoComponent For="() => _myDto.MyProperty" />
```

Note that the method GetMemberExpression is a custom extension method used to extract the MemberExpression from an expression tree, and you may have to implement that along with ReplaceCamelCaseWithSpaces.

Here's an example implementation of GetMemberExpression:

```
public static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression<TValue>(this Expression<Func<TValue>> expression)
{
    if (expression.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression)
    {
        return memberExpression;
    }
    else if (expression.Body is UnaryExpression unaryExpression && unaryExpression.Operand is MemberExpression)
    {
        return (MemberExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I make sure that `For` is never uninitialized?

Comment: `[EditorRequired`